# Displaying all table data relating to the filter

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Management commands to display a result from a table i have got it to work to display the PK and the name of the customer relating to that job.

How would i go about showing all the data in that table row.

Example, right now i get returning

```
$ [<Job: 36172 - Customer Name Example>]
```

there are other columns in the table that can be returned but how do i do this?

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
# Show this when the user types help
    help = "My test command"

    # A command must define handle()
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        Job_set = Job.objects.all().filter(serial_no = 66666)
        self.stdout.write(Job_set, ending='')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.SLA
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you write all of your model?

I think [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#comparing-objects) little helpful. You can load some property like that

```
some_entry.id == other_entry.id
```

Comment: The data is already in the table, i am trying to display all the data in the table relating the the date set with a serial number of 66666 but it only displays the pk and customer how do i get other fields to show. So like there is a status field. How would i get that to show?                                          I thought it has something to do with def __str__(self):

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
values_list('DataFeild','DataFeild','DataFeild','DataFeild').filter(example=89)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should filter the table first and then select the column you want to show as follows :

result will be list of the touple.

```
result = models.objects.filter(example=89).values_list('DataFeild','DataFeild','DataFeild','DataFeild')
```

result will be list of dictionary.

```
result = models.objects.filter(example=89).values('DataFeild','DataFeild','DataFeild','DataFeild')
```